# Using the find command in Krunner

Tags: find, krunner

I am a big fan of krunner. But eversince I came across it I have been disappointed by its search function. When I am searching for a specific expression I normally use:

```
find . -iname '*heavymetal*'
```

The find-command ist very useful on my view. I frequently try to search with krunner but it is not presenting sufficient output.

So my question is:

Either: Is there a special syntax within krunner, which is giving me the same output or a compairable output to the find command?

Or: Is it possible to implement the find command into krunner or make a small script which can be implemented into krunner?

Comment: What happens if you just type `heavymetal`?

Comment: Of course some good voices out of my amp ;) hehe ...sory just joking...I give another example: When i type in `Scotland` in krunner, krunner is giving me no output at all. But with the find command the file in question is showing up.

Comment: Do you have `baloo` enabled?

Comment: Yes as far as I see it is activitated and running...